# I want to study number theory

Tags: number-theory

I want to study particular problems in number theory but I have learning disabilities.  I can't really read, and don't retain much from my mathematical education.  The only things I retain are things I self derive, and those things are a pain in the butt and take forever.  Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Try also http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs to Math.Educators and has been posted there as well.

Comment: @wythagoras: I may be wrong, but I think MathEducators.SE approaches questions from the **teachers**' point of view, so I fail to see why this would belong there? As you see, the question has been put on hold there (though not for being off-topic, so it's not clear that my impression is correct either).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It looks like this user is self learning number theory, and they have a tag for self-learning, which is why I said it would probably fit better there.

Answer (score 2):

Self derive!!

Glad to see that. This reminds me of a number theory book I got my hands on as a high school student.

[Joe Roberts, Elementary Number Theory - a Problem Oriented Approach](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory_841).

The book is essentially in two parts. The first part gives you some definitions, but there are no theorems. Or rather, the theorems are all exercises. The exercises are split into smaller steps, and your job is to solve /prove them. If you get stuck, you can take a peek in part two, where there are more details.

Towards the end the material gets a bit deeper, but the early chapters (well over half of the book) are very pleasurable and accessible.

The book is printed in calligraphy.

Not sure that this fits your needs, but something about your post made me want to recommend it. It may be possible to get your hands on a copy at a (university?) library near you. I don't know if a printed version is available (hopefully posting the above link does not violate any laws, if it leads to a scanned copy).

Comment: Here you can buy it, but it is costly... http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Number-Theory-Oriented-Approach/dp/0262680289

Answer (score 1):

The only way to learn *anything* in math is to derive it yourself, so you're actually doing it right. People who just memorize without understanding aren't doing themselves a favor, at least not in this field. You might find that playing around with the concepts will help you understand it better and allow you to find results on your own more easily, so I encourage that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Its great that you can $self derive$.Spend some more time reading books on the number theory.And as you said it takes more time to retain or understand things try to study in less and do it with someone else like a friend.Discuss it with him and try to explain your views to him and see if they are correct.try out interesting problems rather than the ones that only need mathematical calculation.There are plenty of interesting problems in number theory including problems on real life.You are bound to like them and spend the whole day thinking about the problems.